# How to set the file path to project files from excutable file?

Tags: c#, winforms, filepath

i am new to C# how can i set file path to project files 
     i have tried these but it gives default windows file path how to do that?

```
  sfdlg.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath + @"..\..\";
    Application.StartupPath---> is my excutable file path. from this path to come back two `root folders` i use `@"..\..\"`
```

is there any way to get back to Two root folders?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need this path?

Comment: i want to set initial path(where all project files are stored)

Comment: The initial path of what? For what reason?

Comment: to save any .docx, or .pdf files (user friendly i.e. no need to browse files from windows initial directory)

Comment: I think the OP wants to go two steps back from the executable path..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inverted the path specifications - the `..` should be at the *start* of the path (assuming no drive name is there).

A safe way to use paths is to use them with the [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class:

```
Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, ".."), "..");
```

The above should do the trick.